# Want to upgrade python for django

Tags: linux, redhat, python, django

I would like to upgrade python for django. Currently I have python 2.4.3 on my Red Hat server. I have installed python 2.7.1, but the default python is *still* 2.4.3 (It didn't upgrade python, but installed python 2.7 separately). Django python version is also still 2.4.3 as well. I want to make a change so Django runs with 2.7. How do I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RedHat has many tools that depend on Python 2.4 (`yum` is an example of this) so make sure you don't overwrite the standard Python binary.

Depending on how you installed it, you may be able to get to it with the command `python27` or `python2.7`. So instead of running
`python ./djangoapp.py`
run
`python2.7 ./djangoapp.py`

If that doesn't work, you might need to reference the Python binary directly as it might not be in the system path. From memory, it should be something like `/installpath/bin/python`. You might want to symlink that into /usr/bin or something so it's available in your system path, just make sure to name it python2.7 or python27 not just Python.

Comment: @samarudge Sorry to ask you this noob question, but when you run `python2.7 ./djangoapp.py`, do you use this step in the configure process?  If I past this line in my terminal and run it I get `python2.7: can't open file './djangoapp.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @Shehzad009 No that's nothing to do with setting it up, when you run `python2.7 --version` does it print back the correct version number? If so, everything is working, but when you launch your django app instead of using the `python` command use the `python2.7` command

Comment: @samarudge Running this `python2.7 --version` works. Typing `python2.7 ./djangoapp.py` does not work. `python2.7: can't open file './djangoapp.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @Shehzad009 I was using ./djangoapp.py as an example, you should replace it with the path to your django application's main file. That means you have Python 2.7 working correctly you just need to run your application with it

Comment: @samarudge  so if my project folder is c2duo_mms, and my inside this folder I have an mmc folder which holds my forms/views/models - etc. So I should replace  djangoapp.py with mmc? EDIT: I get this error. `/usr/local/bin/python2.7: can't find '__main__' module in './mmc'`

Comment: I have figured out the answer. You must install mod_wsgi again for python 2.7 (at least in my case). You will also need to install any other dependencies/libraries for python 2.7 as well if you have done so for python 2.4

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider running [virtualenv](http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/), located on [PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). It sets up a virtual environment for running different versions of Python, which allows you to avoid interfering with the system's Python 2.4.

I have the same problem on my CentOS VPS, and found `virtualenv` as the solution. It's not *quite* as simple as everyone says (when you build third-party packages that aren't Python-based, say that compile in C, you have to make sure they point to the right Python libraries for compilation). But it generally works nicely.